# How do I automatically import data in sites using API to Google spread sheet?

Tags: api, google-sheets

I am interested in importing data to spreadsheet automatically.

I have used magic script to import GA data to google spreadsheet, and it was awesome.

But there're more data other than GA that need to be automatically updated, like my advertisement sales records to compare daily CTR, revenue from various sites.

These sites are NOT related to Google, but i know they provide API, so i was hoping to get data to google spreadsheet using App script.

if there's something like magic script for outside API, it'll be awesome. When i have looked into it, however, I couldn't find any.

So my question is this,

1. Is there a way to import data automatically to google spreadsheet using API(sites that are not related to google) and App script? If there is, please tell me how.
2. Is there any written (free) script for that, like the case of GA and magic script?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes you can do that with google apps script performing a urlfetch [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/twitter_tutorial?hl=fr) a complete exemple with twitter (unfortunately it's not a solution for beginers).
2. it depend of the site/api in all case you'll need to google that to have a real answer. There is not an official repository for that.